# Laravel request() input file and input hidden with same name

Tags: php, laravel, file, input, request

I have simplified my form for this question.

This is my example

```
<form method="post" name="test" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {{csrf_field()}}
   <input class="form-control" type="file" name="test[]" id="companion"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="test[]" value="random-value" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In my route a just *dd* the request as follow:

```
dd(request('test'));
```

Now I would expect an array with a file (UploadedFile type) and the *random-value*, instead, I'm getting only the file.

```
array:1 [▼
   0 => UploadedFile {#539 ▶}
]
```

Any idea why I'm getting this result? 
I know that I can change the name of the variables, but I wanna understand why it doesn't work like that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm going to guess it's because of the different input types. If they were the same input type, it would work fine, but the file input type works differently.

Comment: @aynber do you know how can I get both in a single array?

Comment: Nope, I do not. If all you have is a single file and hidden variable in one form, then you shouldn't need an array.

Comment: No unfortunately not, I have a complex form, and I'm doing the *edit* action, and some values can be files or static content.

Comment: You need to change your approach, On edit view you need to load the uploaded files and show them with option to delete and then if the file is deleted you can allow to upload the new file or something. I am just throwing ideas at you :)

Comment: @lewis4u I'm already doing it, but each file has different related information, this is why I need to echo the ID in a hidden input, but I also allow the user to add new files (with new info), and this is how I got the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I might have found a solution.

Since I'm editing, I know if the file/hidden input is new (as in the edit I can add other items) or got from the DB.

```
<form method="post" name="test" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {{csrf_field()}}
   <input class="form-control" type="file" name="test[]" id="companion"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="test[id-{{id}}]" value="random-value" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

With this "fix" I will manage to get my goal.

```
dd(request('test'));
------------------------
array:2 [▼
  "id-1" => "random-value"
  0 => UploadedFile {#539 ▶}
]
```

I do not care about the keys so I'm happy with this solution.

NB this is just a simplification of my problem but it helped me to understand it.

I hope it'll help other people =)

Feel free to ask me if you have any question ;)

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

It's because:

1. You call `request('test')`. This made a call to the helper in [`Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8808758b49cd9ff4110317f698e3e3d082876d98/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L707-L720)

   ```
   function request($key = null, $default = null)
   {
       ...
       $value = app('request')->__get($key);
       ...
   }
   ```
2. This directs the call to the `__get` method to quickly get a value in [`Illuminate\Http\Request.php`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/04d90b85cd486b217961900ebca5be783367cb88/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L659-L666)

   ```
   public function __get($key)
   {
       if (array_key_exists($key, $this->all())) {
           return data_get($this->all(), $key);
       }
       ...
   }
   ```
3. The problem lies in the `all()` method defined in the trait [`Illuminate\Http\Concerns\InteractsWithInput`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/d93d0faea59015b92562c6146d16b923f383a245/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php#L163-L178)

   ```
   public function all($keys = null)
   {
       $input = array_replace_recursive($this->input(), $this->allFiles());
       if (! $keys) {
           return $input;
       }
       ...
   }
   ```

So you see what's going on here? You actually still have the `test[]` hidden value, but the `all()` method simply merged it with files with the same name. I assume it's for the sake of simplicity on why they would do this, and I don't think it's *that* common to have two inputs with the same name, with different input type.

I guess, the simplest solution here now is, to access it via the `request` instance. Try this (untested, theoretically should work):

```
\Log::info(app('request')->file('test'));
\Log::info(app('request')->get('test'));
```

And find the output in `laravel.log` file. You should be able to do a simple array merge with them.